# Why does "Exception in thread" occur?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am working on a program on eclipse and I am getting an error that says, : **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at main.main(main.java:19)**
I am new to programming, it would mean a lot if you tell me what the error is about and how i can fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to run code that has errors in it - you need to fix the errors that Eclipse is telling you about.

Comment: Welcome to the stacks.  Prepare the smallest example of code that exhibits the error.  By preparing such a code example, questioners sometimes find the solution. In any case it makes the task easier to answer.

Comment: Welcome, add your code so we can help you better

Answer (score -1):

Try running the "Clean..." command in the Project menu.  It may not help, but it is a good step to at least eliminate that possible source of spurious error.

Comment: how would that resolve a compilation problem?

Comment: I've had compilation errors, for example from incorrect usage of egit, that disappeared when running Clean...

Comment: @Stultuske the link provided at the top upon closing the question points to a question where the person was able to resolve their problem by Cleaning.

Comment: keep in mind we haven't seen any of the OP's code, so we don't know exactly what caused the issue. The above might be a fix. It might also not be.